# Assign date values for null in a column in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe:

```
Location        Month       New_Date    Sales
USA             1/1/2020    1/1/2020    34.56%
COL             1/1/2020    1/1/2020    66.4%
AUS             1/1/2020    1/1/2020    32.98%
NZ              null        null        44.59%
CHN             null        null        21.13%
```

Im creating `New_Date` column from `Month` column (MM/dd/yyyy format).
I need to populate `New_date` values for the rows having `Month` as null.

And this is what I tried:

```
df1=df.filter(col('Month').isNull()) \
.withColumn("current_date",current_date()) \
.withColumn("New_date", trunc(col("current_date"), "month"))
```

But Im getting first date of current month.
I need the first date of `Month` column
Pls suggest any other approach.

```
Location        Month       New_Date    Sales
USA             1/1/2020    1/1/2020    34.56%
COL             1/1/2020    1/1/2020    66.4%
AUS             1/1/2020    1/1/2020    32.98%
NZ              null        1/1/2020    44.59%
CHN             null        1/1/2020    21.13%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `first` function over window:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = (Window.orderBy("Month")
     .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
     )

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "New_date",
    F.coalesce(F.col("Month"), F.first("Month", ignorenulls=True).over(w))
)

df1.show()
#+--------+--------+--------+------+
#|Location|   Month|New_date| Sales|
#+--------+--------+--------+------+
#|      NZ|    null|1/1/2020|44.59%|
#|     CHN|    null|1/1/2020|21.13%|
#|     USA|1/1/2020|1/1/2020|34.56%|
#|     COL|1/1/2020|1/1/2020| 66.4%|
#|     AUS|1/1/2020|1/1/2020|32.98%|
#+--------+--------+--------+------+
```